# Solution to set precision errors

Tags: c++

Where am I going wrong? I inclduded setprecision(2) but the output comes wrong.
example: if the sum is 23 and n is 10, the answer is 2.00

```
for(i=3; i<n; i++)
{
    sum=sum+marks[i];
}
cout<<"Total marks of the student is "<<sum<<endl;
avg=sum/n;
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed;
cout<<"Average marks of the student is "<<avg<<endl;
getch();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `setprecision`. `int / int` is `int`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using the [**integer division**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), in which the fractional part (remainder) is discarded.

Change

```
avg=sum/n;
```

to

```
avg=sum/(float)n;
```